# React Hot Reload with Redux-Saga

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, redux, redux-saga

I'm using React Hot Reloader on my project and recently noticed a strange behavior of the redux store in pairs with Hot Reloader.

When I load the page for the first time, my page component calls an action to retrieve a particular data (this is doing in `useEffect` hook), everything works fine - action triggers once and calls backend properly:
[image: Single call pic]

When I make a change in the code and save it, Hot Reloader reloads my component and dispatch action twice (as a result - 2 calls in the network tab):
[image: Two calls pic]

Same story with further code changes:
[image: Three calls pic]

I wrap my main app component and redux store with hot reload middleware:
**index.js**

```
// Create a reusable render method that we can call more than once
const render = () => {
  // Dynamically import our main App component, and render it
  const MainApp = require('./MainApp').default;
  ReactDOM.render(
    <MainApp />,
    rootEl,
  );
};

if (module.hot) {
  module.hot.accept('./MainApp', () => {
    const MainApp = require('./MainApp').default;
    render(
      <MainApp />,
      rootEl,
    );
  });
}

render();
```

**store.js**

```
const store = createStore(reducers(history), initialState,
    composeEnhancers(applyMiddleware(...middlewares)));

sagaMiddleware.run(rootSaga);

if (module.hot) {
  // Enable Webpack hot module replacement for reducers
  module.hot.accept('../reducers/index', () => {
    const nextRootReducer = require('../reducers/index');
    store.replaceReducer(nextRootReducer);
  });
}
```

Are there any ways to fix that? Why it is happening?

Comment: Are the actions dispatched from the same component?

Comment: Are you sure that action is dispatched twice (vs one more listener attached to the same action)?

Comment: Not sure about the issue, but if its something react-hot-loader related, perhaps using https://github.com/pmmmwh/react-refresh-webpack-plugin instead might help.

Comment: @HMR, yes, actions are dispatched from the component

Comment: @AlekseyL. yes, actions are dispatched twice from useEffect hook

Comment: I think that's the problem with components delete - Hot Reload module just don't delete the old component, and as a result we have 2 components after hot rerender - old one and new one.
I don't know how to check/solve that